# Jenkins - Advanced Project Display Name

Tags: jenkins

In the last war update (1.514) the list of project names (under the "All" tab) has changed to list the "Project Name" instead of the Display Name listed in the Advanced Project Options. The Advanced Display Name still shows during the build on the node. How can I get it back to displaying the Advanced Display Name?

Answer (score 0):

This is [fixed in 1.515](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17715):

> - Display Name is not shown. (issue 17715)